# regex for specific number of numbers

Tags: regex

I need to get the regex-pattern for the following sequence of numbers:

```
X.XXX.XXX-X
```

Every `X` is one number.

How can I do that? I don't want to use *, because I need exactly the number of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use braces to specify the number of occurrences:

`\d{1}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{1}`

`{3}` will match the previous token exactly 3 times. You can also specify a range like `{1,5}` which will match the previous token between 1 and 5 times. This is a greedy match and will match as many characters as possible.